# preg_replace returning null, can't see an error with my RegExp

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to strip all non-number, non-word characters from a string (except hyphens) to create a URI stub. I have the following code:

```
$urlPrefix = strtolower($this->urlPrefix.(substr($this->urlPrefix, -1) == '-' ? '' : '-'));
$urlPrefix = preg_replace('#\s+#', '-', $urlPrefix);
var_dump($urlPrefix);
$urlPrefix = preg_replace('#[^\d\w\s-]#g', '', $urlPrefix);
var_dump($urlPrefix); exit;
```

If I set `$this->urlPrefix = "Test replace$%^*";` then the first `var_dump($urlPrefix)` outputs `test-replace$%^*-` as expected, but the second dump is outputting `NULL`, but I can't see anything wrong with my regexp, can someone please help me? Why is `preg_replace` erroring?

Comment: `/g` is not a valid regex flag for PCRE. Enable `error_reporting`.

Comment: I do have `error_reporting` enabled, it's forced on as it's a development server. Not sure why it didn't show that error though.

Comment: Then it's perhaps `display_errors` that somehow got disabled. As last resort you can often try `set_error_handler("var_dump");` temporarily.

Comment: If `null` is returned use use `preg_last_error_msg()` to get the regex error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g` cannot be used with `preg_replace`. Here, this [sample code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdjB0RVRqTllFOGM) works alright:

```
<?php
   $urlPrefix = "test-replace$%^*-";
   $urlPrefix = strtolower($urlPrefix.(substr($urlPrefix, -1) == '-' ? '' : '-'));
   $urlPrefix = preg_replace('#\s+#', '-', $urlPrefix);
   var_dump($urlPrefix);
   $urlPrefix = preg_replace('#[^\d\w\s-]#', '', $urlPrefix);
   var_dump($urlPrefix);
   exit;
?>
```

Output:

```
string(17) "test-replace$%^*-"                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
string(13) "test-replace-"
```

Comment: What do you mean by `g cannot be used with preg_replace` statement? PHP by default will do a global match, so we don't need to put the `g` modifier explicitly. It's isn't related to `preg_replace`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: that is exactly what I meant. It is not necessary there, and will cause a warning.

Comment: `g cannot be used with preg_replace` makes me to think like `preg_replace` function is the one which won't allow `g` modifier wher the other func like `preg_match` or `preg_match_all` would allow.